# In Reference class - The method "get_tree()" isn't declared in the current class error in Godot

Tags: null, save, instance, godot, gdscript

I am currently working on my game's save and load states, and I created a global script to use it. The script extends Reference class and uses the .dat file extension for saving and loading files. But I can't use the method `get_tree()` in the script.
I get the error: `The method get_tree() isn't declared in the current class.`

I think the problem is that Reference is not connected to the SceneTree. So I tried using a player instance and use get_tree() on that like this:

```
const PLAYER_CHARACTER = preload("res://Player/Player.tscn")

var player = PLAYER_CHARACTER.instance()

player.get_tree().change_scene("res://Map/" + player_data.scene)
```

But then I get this error: `Attempt to call function 'change_scene' in base 'null_instance' on a null instance.`

I am a little confused on how to change the scene from this script when I load a save file. I need this to complete my save and load states.
The code is here:

```
extends Reference

get_tree().change_scene("res://Map/" + player_data.scene)
```

I appreciate any kind of explanation on why this is the case and any godot docs that can help me better understand this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `get_tree` exists in `Node` (and derived classes). Notice that `Node`s exists in the scene tree.

However `Reference` has no relationship with the scene tree.

Furthermore, news: You can create, from code, multiple `SceneTree`s (not something you need to do for 99.99% of games, but the option is there).

Therefore, it is not a concern of `Reference` to be able to get the `SceneTree`, *and if it were, it won't be clear which one to get*.

---

The issue with this code:

```
const PLAYER_CHARACTER = preload("res://Player/Player.tscn")

var player = PLAYER_CHARACTER.instance()

player.get_tree().change_scene("res://Map/" + player_data.scene)
```

Is that `get_tree()` gives you `null` because the instance `player` is not in a `SceneTree`.

---

Now, presumably you want the default `SceneTree`. For that there is a work around:

```
var scene_tree := Engine.get_main_loop() as SceneTree
```

The `SceneTree` class extends the `MainLoop` class. And by default, the main loop of Godot uses an instance of `SceneTree`.

So the above line of code would work unless you changed the type of the main loop to something else. *Which, again, you can (probably not something you would do for a game, but for some utility applications it makes sense - Yes, using Godot for non-game software).*

---

With that said, I would like to encourage you to look for a different design. For changing the current scene we would often use an [Autoload (singleton)](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/singletons_autoload.html), which become available from everywhere in the scene tree, plus they persist when the scene changes.

*Keep in mind that extending `Reference` will make your class reference counted.*

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I actually changed to using autoloads instead of my previous file because of your comments. They are much easier to understand and use